# VPN Adapter creation fails inside Ubuntu Docker container, except on LCOW?

Tags: docker, vpn, cisco, tunnel, docker-for-windows

Basically, I am building a container that connects to a VPN.  It happens to use AnyConnect, but I do not think that matters.

My dockerfile looks like this.

```
FROM ubuntu

COPY anyconnect/ /anyconnect/

WORKDIR /anyconnect/vpn
RUN echo y | ./vpn_install.sh

WORKDIR /
COPY start.sh .
RUN chmod 777 start.sh

EXPOSE 1080

ENTRYPOINT [ "/start.sh" ]
```

That start script looks like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Allow tunneling.
mkdir -p /dev/net
mknod /dev/net/tun c 10 200

# Start services.
/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpnagentd -d > agent-stdout.txt 2> agent-stderr.txt &

# Connect to VPN.
/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn connect $1

# Run a daemon here that keeps the container alive.
```

Finally, I kick off the container like this.

```
docker run -it --rm --cap-add=NET_ADMIN vpn-connector uri.to.vpn.com
```

The output of the VPN connect statement seems to run into an error on "The VPN client driver encountered an error.  Please restart your computer or device, then try again."

```
  >> state: Connecting
  >> notice: Establishing VPN session...
  >> notice: Establishing VPN - Initiating connection...
  >> notice: Establishing VPN - Examining system...
  >> notice: Establishing VPN - Activating VPN adapter...
  >> state: Disconnecting
  >> notice: Disconnect in progress, please wait...
  >> error: The VPN client driver encountered an error.  Please restart your computer or device, then try again.
  >> state: Disconnected
```

So, it seems like there might be an issue where the `cscotun0` that the AnyConnect client would normally create cannot be created properly.  I have tried this on Linux, Mac, and Linux-mode on Windows, and they all fail with the same error.  **However, in a cruel turn of events, the connection succeeds only when this container is run using LCOW (i.e., Docker for Windows with Windows containers selected).**

I have tried everything.  I have tried `--privileged`.  I have tried mounting `/dev/net/tun` from the host.  I have tried SNAT rules on the host, etc.  Nothing has worked.  It only works on LCOW, and I have no idea why that is the only scenario in which the interface is created successfully and the connection succeeds.

Any ideas, friends?

Answer (score 4):

It appears that the problem is that docker mounts certain files like `/etc/resolv.conf` to keep them up-to-date with host system changes.

The fix I found was to add `--cap-add=SYS_ADMIN` to the `docker run` command (to allow unmounting).  Then, I had to physically unmount the file in a startup script.

```sh
cp /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.bak
umount /etc/resolv.conf
cp /etc/resolv.conf.bak /etc/resolv.conf
```

After that, it seemed to work just fine.

Comment: You, just saved my day! I recommend installing kmod dependency for lsmod

Comment: Fix works in Docker engine for Linux as well. Thank you!